# Code executes properly in Xcode but no Terminal

Tags: c, xcode, terminal

Why this C code won't execute properly within Terminal but runs fine in Xcode?

```
int main () {

    int farh, celcius;
    int lower, upper, incr;

    lower = 0;            // The lowest fahrenheit tempeture allowed.
    upper = 300;        // Highest fahrenheit temperature allowed.
    incr = 20;            // The increments in which the fahrenheit increases until it reaches (upper)

    printf("Thanks for using our converter!\n ");

    farh = lower;
    while (farh <= upper) {

        celcius = 5 * (farh - 32) /9;
        printf("%d\t%d\n", farh, celcius);
        farh = farh + incr;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: The terminal output only shows looping up to 200, while your code goes to 300.  Make sure that the code you posted is the code you're compiling and running.

Comment: Just tried your posted code (adding a `#include <stdio.h>`): compiled with gcc and ran within xterm (another terminal emulator). The output seems to be correct, with proper tabs and newlines as expected.